# Regex for multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a pattern for multiple lines

I am new to regex and heavily using them using in my project

I need to come up with a pattern that will match a few group of lines. The pattern should

match either these lines

```
* Source: Test                     *


*                                  *
```

or

```
Ord. 429 Tckt. 1
```

or

```
Guest:
```

Yes, it is not clear. I got a pattern for the second line ( Ord. 429 Tckt. 1) which is:

```
[\s]+[\w]+[\.][\s]+[\d]+[\s]+[\w]+[\.][\s]+[\d]+
```

Comment: why do you need one regex for these three completely different things? isn't it better to separate it into three different expressions?

Answer (score 1):

If you need one large regex to match all of these, the following should work if you have the `Pattern.DOTALL` and `Pattern.MULTILINE` flags set (see [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/RiPgU7DPHO)):

```
^\*[^\n]*\*$.*?^\*[^\n]*\*$|^\w+\.[ \t]+\d+[ \t]+\w+\.[ \t]+\d+$|^Guest:[^\n]*$
```

Here is a breakdown of the different sections (split by the `|`):

Your first group of lines:

```
^\*[^\n]*\*$.*?^\*[^\n]*\*$
---------------------------
^             # start of a line
\*            # a literal '*'
[^\n]*        # any number of non-newline characters    
\*            # a literal '*'
$             # end of a line
.*?           # any number of characters, as few as possible (includes newlines)
^\*[^\n]*\*$  # repeat of the first six elements of pattern as described above
```

The second line portion (for lines like 'Ord. 429 Tckt. 1') is adapted from yours with some minor changes.

```
^\w+\.[ \t]+\d+[ \t]+\w+\.[ \t]+\d+$
```

As for the third, it should be pretty basic, start of a line followed by 'Guest:' and then any number of non-newline characters.

```
^Guest:[^\n]*$
```

Comment: Thanks F.J., but I m trying to match all three with a single regex.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work on http://www.rubular.com/r/RiPgU7DPHO.

But, it's not working on my test link yet. I set both MULTIPLE LINES and DOTALL flags on. It should work, too

Comment: By the way, you need `Pattern.MULTILINE` only if you want to use `$` for the end of lines. If you are okay using whitespace patterns, you can just use `Pattern.DOTALL`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using Java. You would be using `java.util.Regex`. You are probably looking for the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag on `Pattern`. This treats line terminators as a character that you can match with `.`.

Pattern.compile("^*\sSource: Test\s**\s*", Patther.DOTALL);

It depends on how strict you want to be, but the above will match the first line in the first snippet (including the line terminator).

If you need more help with the API or this is the wrong API, edit your question to be clearer.

Are you trying to match all three in a single regex? It can be done, but the patter will be a bit ugly. I can probably help with that too.

A decent regex tester page is: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm. You can do a google search for something like `regex java tester`.

Just one last thing, the pattern at the bottom won't do what you want if I understand fully.

[\s]+ matches one or more spaces, so whitespace is required on the front. Also, you don't need the square brackets. They work, but are only needed for alternation. If you wanted to match either `a` or `b` but not both: `[ab]`. But, if you want to match just `a`, you just put `a` in your pattern.

\s+ one or more spaces
\w+ one or more word chars (no digits or punctuation,etc)
. period
\s+ some whitespace
\d+ some digits
\s+ some whitespace
\w some word chars
. period
\s+ some whitespace
\d+ a single digit

so, 
`\s+\w+\.\s+\d+\s+\w+\.\s+\d+`

Are there supposed to be blank lines in between the `Source: Test` and the line with just the stars?

You are going to end up with something like this:

```
(?:                          # non-capturing group
\s*\* Source: Test\s+\*      # first line of the of the first block
\s+\*\s+\*                   # second line, assuming that there is no space
                             #     between lines or an arbitrary amout of whitespace
)                            # end of first group
|                            # or....
(?:                          # second group (non capturing)
\s+\w+\.\s+\d+\s+\w+\.\s+\d+ # what we discussed before for Org/Tckt
)
|
(?:\s+Guest:)                # the last one is easy :)
```

You may or may not know this, but comments like I have up there can be put into your code via the Pattern.COMMENTS flag. Some people like that. I've also broken up the different groups into their own constant and then pasted them together when compiling the patter. I like that pretty well.

I hope all of this helps.

Comment: I'll try to be clearer. The pattern should match three different instances:
The first instance is any line starting with one or space and containing only the word Guest:

The second instance is any line starting with one or more space followed by the this phrase (Ord. 429 Tckt. 1) and only this phrase.

The third instance should match these as is:

* Source: Test                     *


*                                  *

Comment: Yes, Jeff. I am trying to match all three in a single regex.

Comment: Did you mean 1 or more spaces at the begining? So it fails if there are no spaces in the front of `Ord.`?

Comment: There are one or more space at the beginning of lines for Ord. and Guest

Comment: Good for you. I'm happy to have helped.

Comment: I don't want to sound like I'm whoring for rep, but if this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. This does two things. First, it gives me points, which really isn't the point, but it incentivizes members to do work for you. Second, it allows people that come into this question via searching to see what ultimately helped the most; that is really the most important to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the multi-line switch `(?s)` to the front of your regex:

```
(?s)[\s]+[\w]+[\.][\s]+[\d]+[\s]+[\w]+[\.][\s]+[\d]+
```

Comment: What for?  There's nothing in that regex that will be affected by multiline mode.  Also, `(?s)` turns on DOTALL (or single-line) mode.  `(?m)` is the MULTILINE modifier.

Comment: @AlanMoore Actually you're incorrect there - it's the other way around. See [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)

Comment: Incorrect about what, exactly?  Multiline changes the meaning of the start and end anchors (`^` and `$`), and single-line/DOTALL changes the meaning of the dot (`.`).  Since there are no anchors or unescaped dots in your regex, both modes are irrelevant.  And, while that page doesn't say outright that `(?m)` == multiline and `(?s)` == single-line/DOTALL, the descriptions make it clear which is which.